# Evaluate code block in quarto dependant on evaluation of an R variable

Tags: r, quarto

I have the following quarto document, and I want to execute the second code block depending on the value of `OK`. As below, it does not work. I tried double and triple backticks, using only `OK`, but nothing worked. How can I do this?

````
---
title: "Test"
format: html
---

## Set a variable

```{r}
OK <- FALSE
```

## Running Code depending on value of `OK`

```{r}
#| eval: `r OK`
print("OK is TRUE - otherwise you won't see anything here.")
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use R code as chunk option values by prefacing them with [`!expr`](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/r.html#chunk-options).

````
---
title: "Test"
format: html
---

## Set a variable

```{r}
OK <- FALSE
```

## Running Code depending on value of `OK`

```{r}
#| eval: !expr OK

print("OK is TRUE - otherwise you won't see anything here.")
```
````

---

[image: use of r code as chunk option]

---